# How can I load a stylesheet dynamically in XULRunner?

Tags: javascript, html, xulrunner

When running in a web browser, I can do this to dynamically inject a stylesheet:

```
var link = document.createElement('link'),
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];

link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = '/path/to/stylesheet.css';
head.appendChild(link);
```

Is there a way to do the same in XULRunner? I've seen you can use something called `Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader` to load JavaScript, but does the same capability exist for CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the [*style sheet service*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIStyleSheetService). Something like:

```
var sss = Cc["@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1"]
          .getService(Ci.nsIStyleSheetService);
var ios = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"] .getService(Ci.nsIIOService);
var uri = ios.newURI("chrome://pluginname/skin/notes.css", null, null);

if(!sss.sheetRegistered(uri, sss.USER_SHEET)) {
    sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(uri, sss.USER_SHEET);
}
```

[More examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Stylesheet_Service).